# how to insert multiple rows in MySQL without inserting blank row using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to insert multiple rows with the single query using PDO prepared statement but I don't want to insert any blank row.

Actually, I have four row in my form you can see in HTML below and when I fill only one row it insert three blank row also but I don't to insert any blank row

```
 <form method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="col1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="col2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="col1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="col2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="col1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="col2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="col1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="col2"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

my code is like this

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO foo VALUES(:col1, :col2)');
foreach($data as $item)
{
    $stmt->bindValue(':col1', $item[0]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':col2', $item[1]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

help me please...

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Check with `empty`.

Comment: @Bhavin I edited question you can check my code

Comment: @SmartDeveloper. why your name is same for each tr in first tr it's col1 and in second it's col1 so it's dynamically generated or you make it like this ?  if it's manually generated than you can do it using array take all col1 in array and insert in it using loop because here as per your html it will be over write. and you have to also check with empty. if not empty than insert. so you have to use array for name like col1[] and col2[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As your col1 and col2 is multiple then you should use array: Must change database credential and change table name. Testing purpose i have use table name `test`.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $dbhost = "localhost";  //Set your hostname
        $dbname = "dbname";     //set your dbname
        $dbusername = "root";   //set your db username
        $dbpassword = "";       //set your db password
        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername,$dbpassword);

        for ($i=0; $i <count($_POST['col1']) ; $i++) {
            $rowNum = $i+1;
            if($_POST['col1'][$i]!='' && $_POST['col2'][$i]!=''){
                $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO test(col1, col2) VALUES(:col1, :col2)");
                $res = $statement->execute(array(
                    "col1" => $_POST['col1'][$i],
                    "col2" => $_POST['col2'][$i],
                ));
                if($res)
                    echo "Row no: $rowNum Successfully inserted.<br>";
                else
                    echo "Row no: $rowNum Failed to insert.<br>";
            }else
                echo "Row no: $rowNum single or double field  empty.<br>";
        }
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="col1[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="col2[]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="col1[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="col2[]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="col1[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="col2[]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="col1[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="col2[]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I have edited and now you can see log. Check it now. Must change `database info` and `table name`